# Spring Profile not available in Logback when run via Maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot, logback

I've set up `logback.xml` to select which appender to use based on the active Spring profile. The technique works perfectly when I run the app using

`java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=local path/to/target/application.war`

but not when I run it using the [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/run-profiles.html), e.g.

`mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=local`

Here's the relevant section of the logback.xml

```
<root level="INFO">
    <if condition='"${spring.profiles.active}".contains("local")'>
        <then>
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </then>
        <else>
            <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </else>
    </if>
</root>
```

I will note that the profile does show up correctly in the application itself, just isn't available when processing logback.xml.

The problem also manifests when running from the IntelliJ IDE.

Is there another way to use the Maven Spring Boot Plugin to cause the profile to be visible to the logback.xml parser, and would it work for IntelliJ, as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to configure logback through logback-spring extension?

In your case logback-spring.xml could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/><!-- include  this config if you want to use spring-boot's built-in appenders -->
<configuration>
    <root level="INFO">
        <springProfile name="local">
                <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </springProfile>
        <springProfile name="otherprofile">
                <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        </springProfile>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

More information about available options in logback-spring extensions:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logback-extensions